# EF6 Getting Count In Single Call

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-relationship

Try to do a single database call to get an entity, as well as the count of related child entities.

I know I can retrieve the count using

```
var count = Context.MyChildEntitySet.Where(....).Count();
```

or even MyEntity.ListNavigationProperty.Count()

But That means getting the entity first, followed by another call in order to get the count or use an Include which would retrieve the whole list of related entities.

I am wondering is it possible to add a "Computed" column in SQL Server to return the Count of related rows in another table?

If not how do I ask EF to retrieve the related count for each entity in once call?

I am thinking of possibly using Join with GroupBy, but this seems an Ugly solution/hack.

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public uint NumberOfVotes{ get; private set; }
}
```

which ideally woudl generate SQL Similar to:

```sql
SELECT 
     *, 
     (SELECT Count(*) FROM ChildTable c WHERE c.ParentId = p.Id) NumberOfVotes
FROM ParentTable p
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

You can always drop down to using actual SQL in the following way...

```
string query = "SELECT *, 
                       (SELECT Count(*) FROM ChildTable c 
                       WHERE c.ParentId = p.Id) as NumberOfVotes
                FROM ParentTable p";

RowShape[] rows = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<RowShape>(query, new object[] { }).ToArray();
```

I realize this is not ideal because then you are taking a dependency on the SQL dialect of your target database. If you moved form SQL Server to something else then you would need to check and maybe modify your string.

The RowShape class is defined with the properties that match the ParentTable along with an extra property called NumberOfVotes that has the calculated count.

Still, a possible workaround.

Comment: Select Coun(*) SQL will created by simply context.Table.Count(). But it does mean 2 calls to database which I am trying to avoid.

Comment: At the moment, create a clustered indexed view seems like the best option :/

Comment: That one does, but I want to get the data from the parent table, and for each parent row, get the count on a child row.

Comment: I have updated the example. Really you just add whatever SQL you want as the query and then create a class with the correct properties to match the returned per-row data.

Comment: Yes i know, but then you don't get it back into a strongly typed object and you loose all the type safety :-( May have to write my own extension for something like that query but to generate it from an expression tree.

Comment: The class you create to get the rows is strongly typed. If could be a class derived from the type you already have for the ParentTable but with the addition of a property to match the count.

Comment: ahh ok, so Database.SqlQuery<> will stuff data into this new object without any special mappings?

Comment: Correct. It will try and map the 'select' values into properties with the same name as the 'select' entries. So the NumberOfVotes name you placed in the select statement mean it looks for a property called NumberOfVotes of the return object type.

Comment: Thanks :-) now just to create extensions to be able to include these things! rather than write magic string SQL :-P